# Set selectedRange when NSTextField becomes focused

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, appkit

I'm overriding `becomeFirstResponder` to know when my `NSTextField` is focused. Once focused, I'm trying to move the cursor to the end. The following snippet does not work:

```
@interface MyTextField : NSTextField
@end

@implementation MyTextField

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
  if ([super becomeFirstResponder]) {
    self.currentEditor.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(self.stringValue.length, 0);
    return YES;
  }
  return NO;
}

@end
```

By overriding `textView:didChangeSelection:`, I found that the selection is made, but it's then overwritten by some internal code that runs in response to the `NSEventTypeLeftMouseDown` event.

The logs look like this:

```
location=0, length=25

location=25, length=0 // The desired selection.

location=0, length=0

location=5, length=0 // Where the user clicked.
```

Comment: A little hacky, but you could queue the `self.currentEditor.selectedRang...` code to run on the next event loop.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `mouseDown:` method in your `NSTextField` subclass.

Then, set `selectedRange` *after* calling super.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
  [super mouseDown:event];
  self.currentEditor.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(self.stringValue.length, 0);
}
```

`NSTextField` only has its `mouseDown:` method called when its "field editor" is not yet focused, so the user can still change the selection after the `NSTextField` gains focus.

This isn't a perfect solution, because the user may have focused the `NSTextField` indirectly (eg: with the Tab key). You can always set `selectedRange` in both `mouseDown:` *and* `becomeFirstResponder` though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` from inside `becomeFirstResponder` to ensure the `selectedRange` is set *after* the `NSEventTypeLeftMouseDown` event is handled.

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
  if ([super becomeFirstResponder]) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(textFieldDidFocus) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    return YES;
  }
  return NO;
}

- (void)textFieldDidFocus
{
  self.currentEditor.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(self.stringValue.length, 0);
}
```